# Bind click handler to dynamically created anchor tags fires erroneously and only once

Tags: jquery

My case scenario is :-

```
<div id="dvMyrptflyout"> Some dummy text </div>

<ul id="ulMyRpts" data-col="4" data-row="6" class="flyoutList" style="height: 194px;">
    <li class="newx column1">
       <div>All Partners&nbsp;
           <a class="ancRpt" href="#">Excel</a> | <a class="ancRpt" href="#">PDF</a> |     
           <a data-txt="All Partners" data-filetype="3" class="ancRpt">Share</a>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li class="newx column1">
       <div>Partners and Periods&nbsp;
           <a class="ancRpt" href="#">Excel</a> | <a class="ancRpt" href="#">PDF</a> | 
           <a data-txt="Partners and Periods" data-filetype="3" class="ancRpt">Share</a>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li class="newx column1">
       <div>Schedule M Ammount&nbsp;
           <a class="ancRpt" href="#">Excel</a> | <a class="ancRpt" href="#">PDF</a> | 
           <a data-txt="Schedule M Ammount" data-filetype="3" class="ancRpt">Share</a>
       </div>
    </li>
    <li class="newx column1">
       <div>test 1&nbsp;
           <a class="ancRpt" href="#">Excel</a> | <a class="ancRpt" href="#">PDF</a> | 
           <a data-txt="test 1" data-filetype="3" class="ancRpt">Share</a>
       </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Client side JQ code is as follows:-

```
  $(function () {
              $('#dvMyrptflyout').one("mouseover", bindShareAnc);                
  });


  function bindShareAnc() {
        $('a[data-filetype="3"]').each(function (idx, anc) {
              var $anc = $(anc);
              var name = $anc.data("txt");
              $anc.on('click', openShare(name));
        });
  }

  function openShare(rptName) {
       alert(rptName);
  }
```

Problem  - For some reason, the alerts are getting fired on the page load. It should not fire on the page load. I want to bind the click event to the share anchor tags dynamically. But when i click the share anchor tag, nothing happens.. I guess i got meddled up with the event propagation model.

Please suggest the fix.

Comment: JSFiddle please, much easier to work on this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is almost correct, but inside of `openShare` function, you have to **return a function** for the click handler:

```
function openShare(rptName) {
    return function () {
       alert(rptName);
    }
}
```

That happens because, in this case, the second argument of `on` should be a function. In your implementation `openShare` opens the alert and returns `undefined`.

That's why `openShare` should return a function that contains the `alert(...)` call.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ruzrtcek/)

Comment: replace `.one("mouseover", bindShareAnc); ` with `.on("mouseover", bindShareAnc); `

Comment: @MiG No, that will just add more handlers. And the alert will be called multiple times after multiple hovers.

Comment: It would be better to use .one to make the event binding once for anchor tags. Then on subsequent clicks, it should work fine.

Comment: @Karan Don't forget you have to hover `Some dummy text` text and then click share.

Comment: @Karan But I'd put the handlers inside of the page load handler, and remove `mouseover` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: After mouseover is fired, you click on share, it should show alert and not on page load.

```
$(function () {
              $('#dvMyrptflyout').one("mouseover", bindShareAnc);                
  });


  function bindShareAnc() {
        $('a[data-filetype="3"]').each(function (idx, anc) {
              var $anc = $(anc);
              var name = $anc.data("txt");
            $anc.on('click',{param:name}, openShare);
        });
  }

  function openShare(event) {
       alert(event.data.param);
  }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b027r0um/68/)